# how to use cusor in function to check values from table1 and get inserted in table2?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables table1 and table2, table1 is the log table when transactions get successful the value will get inserted in table1 and table2 is the table that will store consolidated values from table1.

values get inserted in the table1 continuously, so I have to select values from table1 for every 5mins check value in one field, and insert data in table2.

every 5mins there can me 100-1000 records in table1 as well.

how to use cursor in a function?

Comment: Why do you need to use a cursor? All you need is something like: `insert into table2 select * from table 1 where fld = <some_val>`.

Comment: I have to automate the process and when values will be selected from table1 we have to check 2 values and then store in table2

Comment: That does not provide any more information then before. To your question add an example in pseudo code of what you are trying to achieve.